# How can I change the auto formatting positioning of curly braces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

From this:

```
if (condition == true)
{
   // do something
}
```

to this:

```
if (condition == true) {
   // do something
}
```

In School the PC's are used to the second, and I prefer it more. Thought my Visual Studio automaticlly uses the first. How can I change it?

Comment: Don't do that. Don't make C# look like java / javascript. Egyptian braces are evil. BTW doing `== true` is redundant.

Comment: The first part of @HighCore's post is personal preference. You like it that way, by all means. I prefer it that way too. I do completely agree with his point of the redundancy of `bool == true`.

Comment: @HighCore Yeah, well, that's just, like, your opinion, man. (Even though I have them on a separate line myself.)

Comment: @HighCore is just following common C# convention.  It isn't *wrong* to do Egyptian braces.  It's definitely not evil.  It's all about readability.  For C#, it's preferred to avoid it, but it's not necessary.  A good programmer can be familiar and comfortable with any common convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools => Options => Text Editor => C#

There's a ton of options in there for you to tweak as you see fit. It won't maintain from one Visual Studio to another unless you're logged in in the newer versions.

I would also turn stuff like "Line numbers" (under Formatting) on with "All Languages", and not just C#.

Comment: Why would line numbers be useful?

Comment: So that you can tell other people where something is happening in your code, or find where the Stack Trace is telling you that something is going wrong.

Comment: But you can click entries in the stack trace?

Comment: Depending on where it comes from. My company always logs them in a text file on the servers, or sends the formatted Exceptions through emails. You can't click on them that way.

It's just extra information. You don't HAVE to use it, but be prepared for lots of other people to make references to it.

Comment: Wow, then you really need to have the same version of the code to be able to find offending places.

Comment: @AndersLindén That's easy with source control. You are able to find out the exact code you last published within half a minute, right?

Comment: So you log something to be read in half a minute?

Comment: @AndersLindén My comment was a reply to your comment right above it. In case it's a bit unclear, what I meant is that you should be able to find this "same version of the code" really fast.